# Message ALL users before shutdown

Tags: windows

How can I send a message to other users via CMD when I'm on Windows 2008 server?

I usually do `shutdown -r -t 30`, but how can I add a text to this command?

Comment: A key skill for a sysadmin is learning to read documentation. For something basic like this it should be the first place to look. Unsurprisingly the windows and 'Unix' documentation tell you how to do this.

Answer (score 20):

```
shutdown -r -t 30 -c "This system is shutting down in 30 seconds.."
```

The `-c "text"` will add a comment to the display window notifying other users of the shutdown.

For Unix, the syntax would be `shutdown -r -t 30 "This system is shutting down in 30 seconds..`"

Comment: thank you so much :9 is this also possible in unix?

Comment: Added syntax for unix

Comment: Unixes vary. On OS X (and Linux) you want `shutdown -r +5 "message"`, for a shutdown in 5 minutes. (No -t, which specfies the amount of time to let programs exit gracefully.) You can vary the time, but 1 minute is the minimum. A longer time may be better because it actually gives users a chance to react, or perhaps even contact the admin to abort the shudown.  On Solaris you do: `shutdown -y -g 30 -i 6 "message"` for a 30 second shutdown.